# Accessing form fields as properties in a django view

Tags: python, django, forms, validation

According to the Django tutorial, you should access form fields using cleaned_data dictionary. I'm wondering why I can't access the properties of the form directly? My form validates just fine, but when I try to access it, Django complains that the object does not have the attribute. I added some code below that I hope will help diagnose the problem.

Form:

```
class CustomForm(forms.Form):
    description = forms.CharField(widget = forms.TextInput(attrs = {'placeholder' : 'enter some text'}), label = "My form")
```

View:

```
def process_form(request):
    if request.method != 'POST':
        raise Http404

    myForm = CustomForm(request.POST)

    if not myForm.is_valid():
        c = RequestContext(request)
        return render_to_response('home/index.html', {'form' : myForm }, c)

    # debug
    print 'Description: ' + myForm.description # this does NOT work
    # print 'Description: ' + myForm.cleaned_data['description'] # this does work
```

I get the following error: 'CustomForm' object has no attribute 'description'. Did I miss something in the docs that says I can't do that?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The way you define fields using `django.forms` is just a convenient, declarative syntax; it's not really representative of what the final Form class, or an instance of it, looks like in terms of attributes.

Forms have a [metaclass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/100003/what-is-a-metaclass-in-python) (without getting too deep into it, a metaclass is to declaring a class using the `class` keyword as an `__init__` method is to creating an instance of a class using parentheses -- a hook to customise the object being created, which in the case of a metaclass, is a `class`!) which picks off Fields from the form class at definition time and adds them to a `base_fields` dict. When you instantiate a form, its `base_fields` are deep-copied to a `fields` attribute on the instance.

One point of confusion might be that you use `.` to access fields for display in templates -- what's actually happening there is that Django's template engine first attempts to use dictionary-style `[]` access to resolve property lookups and the base form class defines a [`__getitem__`](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getitem__) method to take advantage of this, looking up the appropriate field from the form instance's `fields` dict and wrapping it with a `BoundField`, a wrapper which knows how to use the field and data from the form for displaying the field.

Answer (score 26):

If your form is validated then you can access **myForm** cleaned_data:

```
print myForm.cleaned_data.get('description')
```

If you want to see why you cannot access **myForm.description** then you can see the data dictionary of your **myForm**:

```
print myForm.__dict__
```

Comment: I understand that I can access it using cleaned_data. What I don't understand is why I can't access it using the property itself: myForm.description. What exactly happens under the hood that prevents me from accessing it?

Answer (score 7):

You can access the fields of a Form instance from its fields attribute.

```
myForm.fields['description']
```

And some property like label can be accessed like this:

```
myForm.fields['description'].label
```

**Not sure how to display the value corresponding. Anybody having idea?**

here is my reference

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/api/#accessing-the-fields-from-the-form

Answer (score 4):

You can access your field trought **dict**.

```
form.__dict__["fields"]["description"]
```

Comment: Thank you! How can I set to show only certain form field? I want to do it from view.